# sharepoint 2010 export to excel filtered list

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, filter, export-to-excel

i have a custom list in sharepoint portal. i filtered it and export it but it displayed all item in excel. it ignored filtered results. i searched and found sharepoint 2010 doesn't allow get filtered data to excel. After that i found this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/400720/SharePoint-2010-Export-Selected-Items-to-Excel and i tried it but it didn't work. i don't understand why. Is there any way export filtered list to excel in sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 0):

The link you reference only exports "selected" items---ones your put a check next to.  With some moderate effort, you could modify the code to only export "filtered" items, but I have found it to be much easier to create views.  When you create a view, it will only export the records that appear in that view.

Another approach would be to use the [`GetListItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) Web service to retrieve the items you need to export.

Comment: Nope. I am creating filtered views and yet their very own filters are being ignored.